# Routes with react-router 1.0.0-rc1, express, web pack

Tags: express, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I am fairly new to react and express, so sorry for the newb questions.

In react-router v013.3, I used the below config and "this.context.router.transitionTo(payload.route);" to switch routes, and it worked fine.

However, in react-router v1.0.0-rc1, I've tried both "this.props.history.pushState(null, payload.route);" as well as "replaceState", but they don't render my route.

I cannot use the  class since I have to switch routes programmatically.

This suggests that I add some code to my express config (please see below): https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md#createbrowserhistory

I also added 'historyApiFallback: true' to my webpack dev server config.

Although via console.log message I see history is receiving the route change request, my requested routes do not render.

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Thanks!!!

```
// react-router v013.3
const AppRoutes = (
    <Route path="/" handler={App}>
        <DefaultRoute handler={Home} />
        <Route name="myFieldMapping" handler={MyFieldMapping} />
        <Route name="myValidation" handler={MyValidation} />
    </Route>
);

Router.run(AppRoutes, Router.HashLocation, (Root) => {
    React.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('content'));
});


// react-router v1.0.0-rc1
const myHistory = useBasename(createHistory)({
    basename: '/myApp'
});

let unlisten = myHistory.listen(function (location) {
    console.log('---...---   CALL TO history: ', location.pathname)
});

React.render((
    <Router history={myHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App} >
            <IndexRoute component={Home} />
            <Route path="myFieldMapping" component={MyFieldMapping} />
            <Route path="myValidation" component={MyValidation} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('content'));


// express config
app.get('/myApp/*', function(request, response){
    response.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, publicPath, 'index.html'))
});
```